# Using std vector as a map due to speed, is it reliable?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

For my embedded project I was using an `unordered_map` with hex values as keys and `uint32_t` as values. However they were **very** costly and some benchmarking revealed that using vectors instead were much much faster. (10us vs. 1us during an interrupt which lasts only 50us)

Since the keys are only meant for ordering the values and for readability I did not see any benefit, other than ease of use, over the `unordered_map`.

However, I would like to know if doing something like this is reliable. In the sense that will I lose data and/or ordering after, for example, insert operations to merge 2 vectors together? My vector looks like so: `std::vector<uint32_t>` and the indeces are always different

Another downside of using vectors is that I have to pre-initialize the vector with the required positions which constrains the flexibility of this method.

```
// The PARAM_ values are indeces in HEX
dataMapA.insert(dataMapA.begin() + PARAM_MOTOR_ANGLE, 0);
dataMapA.insert(dataMapA.begin() + PARAM_MOTOR_VELOCITY, 0);
dataMapA.insert(dataMapA.begin() + PARAM_JOINT_ANGLE, 0);
dataMapA.insert(dataMapA.begin() + PARAM_SPRING_ANGLE, 0);
```

If I don't do the above, I can not store any values.

The following could have been a solution but doesn't seem to work when defined as a private/public member. Eclipse throws a syntax error.

```
std::vector<uint32_t> dataMapA(10);
```

So I guess this question can be generalized in how to use vectors as a key-value lookup table and have it be as efficient as possible while still maintaining some sense of readability.

Comment: `std::vector<unsigned char, uint32_t>` isn't a valid vector instantiation, did you mean `std::vector<std::pair<unsigned char, uint32_t>>`?

Comment: `will I lose data and/or ordering after, for example, insert operations to merge 2 vectors together?` Without knowing _how_ you're doing this, how can anyone say? `Another downside of using vectors is that I have to pre-initialize the vector with the required positions which constrains the flexibility of this method.` Can you please clarify what you mean; right now, it's not evident. Are those `PARAM`s meant to be indices? If so, you're throwing them all off every time you `insert()` among them. But then we don't know what the element type is, & if we infer `pair`, that can't be ctord from `0`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That was an error from my part. I fixed it.

Comment: Go lookup `boost::flat_map`

Comment: "doesn't seem to work when defined as a private/public member. Eclipse throws a syntax error." - that *can* work, you just didn't construct the data member correctly, on the member initialization list of each of your constructors. You could also just put a `.resize(n)` call in your constructor body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Problems

```
// The PARAM_ values are indeces in HEX
dataMapA.insert(dataMapA.begin() + PARAM_MOTOR_ANGLE, 0);
dataMapA.insert(dataMapA.begin() + PARAM_MOTOR_VELOCITY, 0);
dataMapA.insert(dataMapA.begin() + PARAM_JOINT_ANGLE, 0);
dataMapA.insert(dataMapA.begin() + PARAM_SPRING_ANGLE, 0);
```

That's definitely not how to set values at given indices. It might work for simple cases, but if you ever `insert()` not strictly in ascending order, you're in for trouble, since each call to `insert(blah, n)` shifts all elements at `n` and greater right by 1 and puts the new element at `n`. So your values in such a case would end up being offset from the 'indices' where you're trying to store them.

`insert()` (while you can bend it to do the job of other methods in some cases) is really for adding new values *amidst or before* old ones, including any moves required to do so.

Anyway, if you haven't `resize()`d the `vector` prior to inserting in it, that's UB right there. The passed iterator needs to be valid for the current `size()`.

If either of these things go wrong... I hope I don't end up being in any vehicle using this `MOTOR`.

## Solution

> If I don't do the above, I can not store any values.

Yes, you can. Call **`resize(n)`** to allocate and default-construct valid elements, and then use **`operator[]`** to access them. *That*'s how you index into a contiguous container. Think of it as an array. In the case of `vector`, it *is*. Use your stdlib's debug version of `operator[]` if you want temporary bounds checking, or `.at(index)` if you want to slow your program down until you expend a lot of energy doing find-and-replace.

An important aside: the dangerously similarly named `reserve()` only reserves memory i.e. increases `capacity()`; it does *not* increase the vector's `size()`, and so the imaginary new indices beyond `[size() - 1]` cannot be used (are UB) until an element is constructed there by one of the proper methods. As I'll outline below, `reserve()` is extremely good... just not with `operator[]`.

## Alternatives

Another case where `insert()` is suboptimal is if you only need to insert values at the `end()` of the `vector`. Then you should use `emplace_back(forwarded, constructor, arguments)` or `push_back(thingToCopy)`. These can be combined with `reserve()`, e.g. if you know 'I will have 50 elements but need to calculate them in a loop' or you just want to overallocate now to reduce the number of reallocations later.

Lastly, if your `vector` always has the same size... why is it a `vector`? Just use an array with compile-time size. Here are examples of both:

```
// if size is not known at compile time:
std::vector<std::uint32_t> dataMapA;
// Calculate dataMapSize at runtime, then
a.resize(dataMapSize);

// if size is known at compile time:
std::uint32_t dataMapA[DATAMAPSIZE]; // DATAMAPSIZE must be constexpr
// or
std::array<std::uint32_t, DATAMAPSIZE>; // if you want its added features, e.g. .at(), copyability

// then in either case:
dataMapA[PARAM_MOTOR_ANGLE] = 0;
dataMapA[PARAM_MOTOR_VELOCITY] = 0;
dataMapA[PARAM_JOINT_ANGLE] = 0;
dataMapA[PARAM_SPRING_ANGLE] = 0;
// and std::array and vector offer .at(n) for bounds-checked indexing
```

And of course, if most of your array elements are to be `0`, then you could construct with `{0}` to fill it, and then just update the few non-zero cases.